# Angular Overrides and Securing Tokens Docker

Tags: angular, docker, azure-devops

I have in Angular different environments:

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    name: "",
    production: false,
    baseApiUrl: "http://localhost:5227",
   }
```

**environment.dev.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    name: "development",
    production: false,
    baseApiUrl: "https://api.myapp.net",
   }
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    name: "production",
    production: true,
    baseApiUrl: "https://api-prod.myapp.net",
   }
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18.18-alpine3.18 As build

WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ /usr/local/app/

ARG ENVIRONMENT=production

RUN echo 'Environment:' ${ENVIRONMENT}

RUN npm run build -- --configuration=${ENVIRONMENT}

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/myapp /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

**Problem 1:**
I have been unable to perform overrides during my docker runs using environment files. So what you see above is the way I do it by performing builds doing filereplacements. I wanted to override at runtime the baseApiUrl.

**Problem 2:**
Sort of linked to 1, but I need to secure some variables e.g. clientid from my authentication etc. Initially I was under the impression of using the environment file and overriding this at build but need to solve problem 1 or have an alternative.
**This is more important than problem 1**

My flow is push to Azure Repos -> Azure Release pipeline which builds and pushes to a docker registry -> deployed. The build pipeline in Azure is where I currently switch between environments e.g. using `--build-arg ENVIRONMENT=development`.

Any ideas on the best way to approach these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem 1

You can use the [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to override the values in `environment.ts` at runtime.

My Sample:

`environment.ts` file in the repo:

```
export const environment = {
    name: "#{name}#",
    production: #{production}#,
    baseApiUrl: "#{baseApiUrl}#",
   }
```

Yaml:

```
trigger:
- none

parameters:
  - name: IsProduction
    type: boolean

variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.IsProduction, false) }}:
    name: development
    Production: false
    baseApiUrl: 'https://api.myapp.net'
  ${{ else }}:
    name: production
    Production: true
    baseApiUrl: 'https://api-prod.myapp.net'

steps:
- task: replacetokens@5
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '**/*.ts'
```

Run the pipeline with different `IsProduction` value:

[image]

[image]

#### Problem 2

In Azure DevOps, you can secure variables by [making them “secret”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash).

Another recommended way to set secret variables is with [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash#use-the-azure-key-vault-task). You can refer [Protecting secrets in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/secrets?view=azure-devops) for more details.